# Per commit reviewing in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, gerrit

Currently we are working with Gerrit for our code reviewing and tbh we love it. We push very small commits, most of the times multiple people on the same branch. We review everything, rebase when needed and merge the hell out of it. It works very good for us. One of the nice extra kicks that we get out of it is that we can spot early problems and especially with junior developers it helps us a lot in training them. (And jeah, we once went till patch-set 35 till it was merged.)

But.. The whole toolset suite is a bit crowded and a separate world. Currently we use:

- Gerrit
- Jenkins
- Jira
- TXT files in directories
- More TXT files in other directories
- Dev servers to put test releases on (by hand)

During my search towards perfection I started to look into team foundation server. This gives us a clean dashboard that captures everything in one nice online environment.

The main downside, we need to work with pull requests to do the code-reviewing. While this works very well with a group of experienced developers, it makes it a bit troublesome with the juniors. Instead of immediately spotting problems they can stay in the code till a point that it is hard to fix them.

So my question is, is there any way to go to a per commit review system in TFS as we have now in Gerrit?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are different systems.

In Gerrit, every commit is a change that stands on its own,  it accepts one patch at a time. Reviews are performed on a per-commit basis, teams that are good at breaking large changes down into small.

In TFS Git it's more like the Github. Please refer to below links to know about the differences between them:

- [Gerrit code review, or Github's fork and pull model?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173262/gerrit-code-review-or-githubs-fork-and-pull-model)
- [Gerrit vs GitHub Pull Request](https://www.dogtagpki.org/wiki/Gerrit_vs_GitHub_Pull_Request)

To review code with pull request in TFS/Azure DevOps you can refer to [Review code with pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.